# Is there a difference between x is null and ReferenceEquals(x, null)?

Tags: c#

When I write this:

```
ReferenceEquals(x, null)
```

Visual studio suggests that the

> null check can be simplified.

and simplifies it to

```
x is null
```

Are those really the same?

Comment: They are equivalent, yes. Although the former is more widely understood. The former is harder to get your head around - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666034/

Comment: Although under the hood, `ReferenceEquals` just calls `return a == b` - [see the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,82), so the super-common `x == null` is just as valid

Comment: @Rhumborl: no -- only if `x` is of a type that does not overload `operator==`. `ReferenceEquals` will never hit that overload (since it operates on values statically typed as `object`), but if you write `==` in your code yourself, you very well can.

Comment: @Rhumborl It's true that `ReferenceEquals` just calls `a == b`. Howerver, since is takes `object` arguments, `ReferenceEquals(x,null)` isn't equivalent to `x == null`, but to `((object)x) == ((object)null)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean the same in this case, yes. Most would use `x == null` though.

I guess `ReferenceEquals` could be little bit confusing because actually `null` is a literal that means *no reference at all*. How can any reference be equal to *no reference*?

Note that `x is null` is only allowed with C#7 and it's [pattern matching feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching). Normally you use `is` to check if `x` is a compatible type but `null` is not a type. So this is a bit confusing as well.

That's why i  prefer `x == null`

Comment: That is actually what confused me.

Comment: Also, why `x is null` is viable? According to MSDN: "[is] Checks if an object is compatible with a given type". Is `null` a type?

Comment: @Sipo: You're right, that's the reason why i prefer `== null` over `is null` ;-)

Comment: I downgraded this answer because it could lead to a stack overflow for those objects that implement operator==(x), and then call x == null in that method. That is why there is a ReferencEquals method or why you need to use x is null

Answer (score 11):

I noticed a lot of answers specifying that `x == null`, `x is null`, and `ReferenceEquals(x, null)` are all equivalent - and for most cases this is true. However, there is a case where you CANNOT use `x == null` as I have documented below:

Note that the code below assumes you have implemented the Equals method for your class:

Do NOT do this - the operator == method will be called recursively until a stack overflow occurs:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyClass x1, MyClass x2)
{
   if (x1 == null)
      return x2 == null;

   return x1.Equals(x2)
}
```

Do this instead:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyClass x1, MyClass x2)
{
   if (x1 is null)
      return x2 is null;

   return x1.Equals(x2)
}
```

Or

```
public static bool operator ==(MyClass x1, MyClass x2)
{
   if (ReferenceEquals(x1, null))
      return ReferenceEquals(x2, null);

   return x1.Equals(x2)
}
```

Comment: You _can_ use `==`, provided you force the default `object ==` comparison by casting the operands to `object`.

Answer (score 3):

> Are those really the same?

Semantically yes (assuming `x` is not a value type). You're doing a null check which is the same for all reference types.

Implementation: no. `x == null` or `x is null` will be directly implemented as IL instructions but `Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)` will be a method call.<sup>1</sup>

Also note if the type of `x` has overridden `operator ==` then `x == null` may not be equivalent (changing the semantics of null checks in an operator overload is, at best, poor code because no one expects such a semantic change).

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course the optimiser could recognise this and just output the IL, you'll need to look at the IL to confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that I'm supre-late to the party and that answers have been given, but I feel the need to summarize a bit since this is a thing I search for every 8-12 months or so and I'd like to have an explanation I can understand (hopefully, if it gets posted)..

### 1. ReferenceEquals(a,b)

This is the tried and tested method to perform a safe reference equality comparison. It basically performs `(object)a == (object)b` (or something to that effect) and has the advantages that its use is instantly recognizable and it can't be **overridden**.

---

### 2. a == b

This method is the one that feels "natural" to most people (since most comparison done throughout C# will be done with this operator).

Default behaviour on reference types should be correct. However, this can be overloaded, which can lead to unexpected results (imagining a failed implementation of the operator overload).

Like @mdebeus said, an additional risk (however marginal even for a competent monkey that read a primer on C#) is causing a `StackOverflowException`. This can appear when overloading == and != and using the operators inside the method itself.

---

### 3. a is b

OK so this is shiny new sort of sugary thing that we get. Microsoft describes *is* in this case with:

> The is operator checks if the runtime type of an expression result is compatible with a given type.
>
> [...]
>
> The E is T expression returns true if the result of E is non-null and
>   can be converted to type T by a reference conversion, a boxing
>   conversion, or an unboxing conversion; otherwise, it returns false.
>   The is operator doesn't consider user-defined conversions.

(read a complete description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-conversion-operators))

The short of it is that this will return true if a can be converted through b via boxing, unboxing or covariance.
As you would expect, this works very well against null.

---

All in all, as a personal note, although **is** makes things shorter and prettier for null check in equality overloading, I think I'll would still use ReferenceEquals, simply because I'm a control-freak and there is at least a part of how **is** works that worries me when it comes to cases of covariance.